# Phonegap on BlackBerry don't write a negative number on html5 input type=number

Tags: html, blackberry, cordova, input, negative-number

I'm developing with Phonegap on BlackBerry and i have a problem with html5 input type number. When i write a negative value, blackberry show this string "22-".  I have tested in Blackberry os 6 and os 7. Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved this problem. I changed **type="number"** to **type="tel"**. 
It is not the most elegant, but it works.